# Default Varnish configuration to use with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, magento-2.1.2

I'm setting up Varnish with Magento 2. I want to know if I can use the default configuration of Varnish (`/etc/default/varnish`) with Magento 2 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure Varnish with Magento 2, the process can be summarized in four steps which are explained as follows:

1. Install Varnish. You can check out this official [MAGENTO2 WITH VARNISH WIKI](https://www.varnish-software.com/wiki/content/tutorials/magento2/index.html) and set up your server accordingly. Make sure that the Varnish version is at least 3.0.5 or any version of 4.x.
2. Login to the Magento 2 Admin Panel and navigate to **STORES** > **Configuration** > **ADVANCED** > **System** > **Full Page Cache** > **Caching Application list** > **Varnish Caching** and create a **Varnish Configuration File (VCL)** for the particular version.
3. Replace your existing **Varnish VCL File** with the one generated from the Magento Admin Panel. Restart Varnish and your Web Server.
4. Visit your store and test everything. See if there is nothing in your `<your Magento install dir>/var/page_cache` directory, it means you have successfully configured Varnish with Magento 2!

**Note: You can also test it by accessing your Magento 2 Homepage to see if you are getting HTTP response headers that indicate Varnish is working.**

For further, you can also check out this official Magento 2 DevDocs about [installing and configuring Varnish with Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html).